# Elgamal algorithm PHP code

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is a PHP implementation for Elgamal algorithm for website data security ?

I found that for EC, Diffie-Hellman but could not find any about elgamal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which ElGamal algorithm are you talking about? [ElGamal encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption), [ElGamal signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme) or are you interested in the [homomorphic properties of ElGamal encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#ElGamal)?

Comment: I meant Elgamal encryption algorithm.

Comment: Off-Topic. Reason: Asks for product recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

There are [GnuPG bindings for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php), and GnuPG implements the [OpenPGP format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), which is about the only standard format covering ElGamal encryption. In any case, you are warmly encouraged *not* to design your own crypto protocol, and instead rely on existing standards like OpenPGP (these things are harder to make correctly than what it seems at first glance).